# Anyway to transform data with a varying derivative into something that can give me comparative percent changes everywhere?

Tags: nonlinear-regression, pre-post-comparison, dependent-variable

Sorry about the confusing title, I am so confused that I don't even know how to frame the question.

I have a device that gives me two sets of output values depending on how I set the surface charge of the surface. The outputs look like this, where output is plotted on y-axis and x-axis is as a result of different surfaces charges.
[image]

[image]

I am interested in a metric, with which I can compare changes to the response outputs as the surface charge is changing. For example, I want to compare the changes to the response of a device with a starting surface charge of -10 to that of a device with a starting surface charge of -5. If the surface of both these devices change by 5, then the % increase of response output 1 is going to be the same for both, as it should be since the same change was made to them. This is the case because the gradient between -10 to -5, and -5 to 0 are the same on response output 1.

Now my problem is that I need to be able to compare changes when not in the linear region of response output. For example, if I have a device that starts out with -5, then goes to 0, and I am comparing that to a device that started out at 0 and goes to 5, the change in the x-axis is the same, yet the %change in the response output is going to be different, as the gradient of the plots are different. This is a huge problem for me, as in the lab I can measure the %change in the response output, from which I need to be able the deduce the surface charge change, but as I outlined, depending on where my device is starting from, I will keep reading different percent changes even for the same surface charge changes, so using the response output's % change is not a valid metric.

Now generally, people use the ratio of response output 1 to that of response output 2, which gives a plot as below:
[image]

Again, here the gradient is different at each surface charge, so %change of the ratio is going to be meaningless for comparison. Furthermore, the curve is not symmetric above and below 1 due to different limits as dictated by the fraction, which is potentially a problem when calculating %changes that go from a ratio of above 1 to below 1, as you are swapping scale essentially (if I am right).

Then finally, I thought about applying a logarithm to the ratio:
[image]

Still there is a problem of changing derivative, but at least it is symmetric above and below 0 now.

Is there any sort of metric or correction you could recommend so that I can compare changes in the way I describe? I was thinking that maybe some sort of metric could be derived that gets corrected by either a sigmoidal fitting of the ratio, or hyperbolic fitting of the log ratio to correct for it.

Ideally the metric would not require me to know exactly what surface charge I start out from, but could give a fairly accurate comparison no matter where I am. I understand that this may be impossible. Less ideally, but what would still be helpful, is to get a metric where I need to know where along the curve my device is to compare changes.

So more mathematically speaking, is there a way to transform my data so that the gradient for any surface charge step is going to give the same metric no matter where I carry out this step.

Hope my description makes some sense,
Really appreciate the help!